# PHP get address as in browser address bar

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to get a page address exactly how it is displayed in the address bar of the browser.

My site is basically a PHP script and my goal is to determine if the users use http://mysite.com or http://www.mysite.com  or just mysite.com or www.mysite.com to access the  site. I hope to use this information to redirect the link so it would be in a single format. This is required for some third party tools I'm using.

so what I'm askin is if it's possible to get the url of a site, in PHP exactly how the browser is requesting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell the difference between `www.mysite.com` and `mysite.com` by looking at `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, however the browser will always automatically add `http://` to a URL (and some browsers hide it from the users as unnecessary information) so there's no way to know what they actually typed in.

Comment: Thank you. That may prove to be enough though. so I'll mark your response as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first two lines of an HTTP request look like:

```
GET /index.php
Host: www.mysite.com
```

The first line specifies the local resource (usually a file in your web directory), and the second specifies what hostname the user entered to find your site (this is especially useful for servers running multiple virtual web hosts). PHP allows you to extract both of these:

```php
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

Technically, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` specifies the filepath of the current PHP script relative to the root directory of this web host, but that should, in practice, be the same as the resource listed on the first line of the HTTP request.

As the other responses have mentioned, there's no way to tell whether the user typed `http://` or not.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine whether or not the user typed http:// or left it off directly from PHP.  PHP will only be able to tell the final domain name (`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`).  The other functionality is handled in the browser.

Comment: How am I outright wrong? Provide an example where you can tell whether or not the user typed http:// in the address bar to get to your site using only PHP.

Comment: Sorry, yeah. just re-read the question. If you'll edit your question, I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: Fair enough.  It was poorly worded